# Problem using custom principal and identity with WCF services

Tags: multithreading, wcf, identity, principal

We are using a custom principal and identity type (ProdigyPrincipal/ProdigyIdentity) because we need extra information within our programs and services. In the program we set the principal and identity. When communicating with a WCF service the principal and identity are set, but after casting to our own type the principal and identity are null.

I noticed that there is a difference between running in Debug mode and Unit Test mode. In Debug mode the type of the principal and identity are of type *WindowsPrincipal* and *WindowsIdentity*. In Unit Test mode the types are GenericPrincipal and GenericIdenity. In both situations when casting to the custom type the value is null.

Setting and getting of the principal/identity is done through *Thread.CurrentPrincipal*.
In the App.configs in the binding section the security mode is set to 'Transport‘.

Used function for settings/getting the principal and identity:

```
  protected static bool SetProdigyPrincipal()
  {
     #region require Thread.CurrentPrincipal should not be null

     if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal == null) // OK
     {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("SetProdigyPrincipal(): Thread.CurrentPrincipal should not be null");
     }

     #endregion require Thread.CurrentPrincipal should not be null

     var prodigyPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ProdigyPrincipal;

     #region require prodigyPrincipal should not be null

     if (prodigyPrincipal == null) // NOT OK
     {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("SetProdigyPrincipal(): prodigyPrincipal should not be null");
     }

     #endregion require prodigyPrincipal should not be null

     // Get the Windows identity from the current principal
     var prodigyIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ProdigyIdentity;

     #region require windowsIdentity should not be null

     if (prodigyIdentity == null) // NOT OK
     {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("SetProdigyPrincipal(): prodigyIdentity should not be null");
     }

     #endregion require windowsIdentity should not be null

     // Create new instance of Prodigy principal
     var newProdigyPrincipal = new ProdigyPrincipal(prodigyIdentity);

     #region require prodigyPrincipal should not be null

     if (prodigyPrincipal == null)
     {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("SetProdigyPrincipal(): prodigyPrincipal should not be null");
     }

     #endregion require prodigyPrincipal should not be null

     // Set the prodigy principal
     var principalIsSet = ProdigyPrincipal.SetCurrentPrincipal(newProdigyPrincipal, ProdigyService.EnterpriseServiceBus);

     // Return principal is set status
     return principalIsSet;
  }
```

Does anyone know why the custom principal and identity type can not be retrieved from *Thread*?

Kind regard, Hans

Answer (score 8):

WCF has a more standard way of achieving the same goal, via a **ServiceAuthorizationBehavior**.

If you set its PrincipalPermissionMode property to "Custom", it allows you to provide a custom `IAuthorizationPolicy` via which you can make a custom `IPrincipal` available to the WCF ServiceSecurityContext. The DispatchRuntime will assign this (your custom) IPrincipal to Thread.CurrentPrincipal - which is what you're after, right?

This is a sample IAuthorizationPolicy implementation:

```
public class DemoAuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
{
    private readonly string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Id { get { return this.id; } }

    public ClaimSet Issuer { get { return ClaimSet.System; } }

    public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext context, ref object state)
    {
        // Here, create your custom principal
        IIdentity customIdentity = new GenericIdentity("myUserName", "myCustomAuthenticationType");
        IPrincipal customPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(customIdentity, new[] { "user", "powerUser" });

        // Set EvaluationContext properties
        context.Properties["Identities"] = new List<IIdentity> { customIdentity };
        context.Properties["Principal"] = customPrincipal;

        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is how you declare the ServiceAuthorizationBehavior in the Web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" >
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="PrincipalPermissionModeDemo.DemoAuthorizationPolicy, YourAssemblyName"/>
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Inside your service you can then leverage declarative security via the `[PrincipalPermission]` attribute, you can get the custom *IPrincipal* from `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, and (alternatively) you can also get the custom *IIdentity* from `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity`.

Hope that solves your issue!

Comment: Good call - I had known about context.Properties["Principal"] being the mechanism for setting the Thread.CurrentPrincipal, but until I used DotPeek on EvaluationContext, I had not known that context.Properties["Identities"] was a shortcut for setting ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity...  If I could throw WCF away, I would....