# Get custom "IIdentity and IPrincipal" client from WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, iprincipal, iidentity

I have a custom IIdentity called **MyIdentity**, and custom IIprincipal called **MyPrincipal**. These classes are used in three different projects:

- ASP.NET MVC
- ASP.NET WebForms
- Windows Forms

These three projects get information from a WCF Service.

It is possible in the WCF Service get the custom IIdentity (**MyIdentity**) and custom IIPrincipal (**MyPrincipal**) when this is called?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following articles-
[custom identity with wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310700/problem-using-custom-principal-and-identity-with-wcf-services),
[custom principle with wcf](http://leastprivilege.com/2007/08/08/custom-principals-and-wcf/)